# No variables watched with tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow 1.15.5 with keras:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    out = net(tf.convert_to_tensor(train_subdata_batch))

[var.name for var in tape.watched_variables()]
```

It returns no value, why ?

I have tried to put a **training=true** argument like this: net(train_data, training=True) but it says:

> TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'training'

Thanks